# Can I compute correlation between two images using imfilter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, correlation

Suppose I want to perform correlation between two images. I know there is a function normxcorr2 which can be used to find the correlation between two images (img1, img2) like this

```
C = normxcorr2(img1, img2)
```

But can I find the correlation using imfilter? Does this command perform correlation?

```
corr = imfilter(img1, img2, 'corr','replicate');
```

When I run the imfilter command and use the imshow() command to output the resulting image, I can see that it is different from what I get when I output the resulting image using normxcorr2 command.The image generated through normxcorr2 looks more like what i would expect from the correlation of the two images. What's the difference between these two methods?

Comment: No, don't get them mixed. The option in imfilter has to do with how to apply the kernel to filter. Also, I am not sure what you are doing, but in the general literature, when you compute the correlation between 2 images, the output is 1 scalar, not an image. Its `corrcoef()` what you generally want

Comment: I'm working on a homework problem where i'm asked to compute the correlation between two images and then show a figure showing the correlation. Also, I have to find the coordinates of maximum correlation(s). So, I suppose the correct way to go is to use normxcorr2, right? @AnderBiguri

Comment: I don't know because I am not your teacher, but yes, likely yes, if your images are like the ones in the documentation (i.e. you are trying to find an image inside another image). But that is corss-correlation, not just correlation, to be technically accurate :).

Comment: They are totally different images(say a zebra and a man). I was confused between imfilter and normxcorr2 but now you cleared my doubt about the imfilter. And the question doesn't even mention cross-correlation. It just asks to compute correlation between the two images. @AnderBiguri

Comment: I am not your teacher, so I can not answer it, but if its asking you to show a figure, it must be the cross-correlation. Otherwise the answer is just 1 value, and you don't generally make a figure of 1 value

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between named functions in MATLAB. To be more specific, `imfilter` function performs a single convolution, and the `normxcorr2` performs correlation between two signals (images). To read more about the difference between convolution and correlation [this link](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/431289-what-is-the-difference-between-xcorr2-filter2-and-imfilter) may help.

There are also other functions in MATLAB namely `xcorr2` to calculate cross-correlation and `filter2` for FIR filtering of img1 by img2.